# Assembly code printing out random characters

Tags: assembly

I tried making an assembly code that prints out the first 10 numbers in the fibonacci sequence but instead I get some random characters like smiley faces. It's the first time I do this if somebody can help me with this thank you!

```
.model small
.data
n dw 10

.code
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov ax, 1
mov bx, 0

mov cx, n

urm: 

mov ah, 2
  mov dx, ax
int 21h

mov si, ax
add ax, bx
mov bx, si  

dec cx

loop urm
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke DOS service [WRITE CHARACTER TO STANDARD OUTPUT](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm) for the first time with

```
   mov ah, 2
   mov dx, ax
   int 21h
```

register `dl` contains the **number 1**, which is not **digit "1"**. You would have to convert it to a character
by `ADD DL,"0"`. Unfortunately it is that easy only for numbers 0..9. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894) how to convert greater binary numbers to a decimal format.

Also look at

```
dec cx
loop urm
```

This looks suspicious, because the instruction `loop` decrements `cx` by itself.